# Sequelize not composing the same queries between enviroments

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm having a problem with Sequelize, as it's generating different querys in localhost and where i have the code deployed. I verified that versions are all the same, but the problem comes when working with underscores.
There are two main models involved:

The ChatThread, the parent of all messages in my chat.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const ChatThread = sequelize.define('ChatThread', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    topicId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'chat_topics',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    name: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: false },
    description: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: true },
    creatorId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: { 
        model: 'USUARIOS',
        key: 'USER_ID'
      },
    },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
    updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    upperCase: false
  });
  ChatThread.hasMany(sequelize.models.ChatMessage, {
    foreignKey: 'threadId',
    as: 'messages',
  });
  return ChatThread;
};
```

The ChatMessage itself, which is related to USUARIOS (Users) and ChatThread:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const ChatMessage = sequelize.define('ChatMessage', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    content: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: true },
    isSpam: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: false },
    sentimentAnalysys: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, allowNull: true },
    threadId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'chat_threads',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'USUARIOS',
        key: 'USER_ID'
      },
    },
    repliedContentId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'chat_messages',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    parentId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'chat_messages',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW },
    updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
  }, {
    timestamps:true,
    underscored: true,
    upperCase: false
  });
  ChatMessage.belongsTo(sequelize.models.USUARIOS, {
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    as: 'user',
  });

  return ChatMessage;
};
```

(I have more relations defined in an external file)
Well, as you can see, the underscored option is se to true. That's creating the columns and table names with underscores instead of camelCase. This is the query in ORM:

```
async findByTopicId({ topicId }) {
      const thread = await this.threadModel.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: this.sequelize.models.ChatMessage,
            as: 'messages',
            attributes: ['createdAt'],
            include: [
              {
                model: this.sequelize.models.USUARIOS,
                as: 'user',
                attributes: ['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME', 'USER_LASTNAME', 'USER_AVATAR'],
              },
            ],
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            limit: 1,
          },
        ],
        where: { topicId }
      });
  
      if (!thread) {
        return null;
      }
      return thread;
    }
```

Im tryng to get the last message in a thread, with its user, so that i can work with that information.

These are the queries generated:

- Localhost

```
`ChatMessage`.`id`, `ChatMessage`.`created_at` AS `createdAt`, `ChatMessage`.`thread_id` AS `threadId`, `user`.`USER_ID` AS `user.USER_ID`, `user`.`USER_NAME` AS `user.USER_NAME`, `user`.`USER_LASTNAME` AS `user.USER_LASTNAME`, `user`.`USER_AVATAR` AS `user.USER_AVATAR` 
FROM `chat_messages` AS `ChatMessage` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `USUARIOS` AS `user` ON `ChatMessage`.`user_id` = `user`.`USER_ID` WHERE `ChatMessage`.`thread_id` IN (1) 
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This works perfectly, look at the OUTER JOIN, **`ChatMessage`.`user_id`**

- Deployed on a VPS

```
SELECT `ChatMessage`.*, `user`.`USER_ID` AS `user.USER_ID`, `user`.`USER_NAME` AS `user.USER_NAME`, `user`.`USER_LASTNAME` AS `user.USER_LASTNAME`, `user`.`USER_AVATAR` AS `user.USER_AVATAR` FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `thread_id` AS `threadId` FROM `chat_messages` AS `ChatMessage` 
WHERE `ChatMessage`.`thread_id` = 1 
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT `id`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `thread_id` AS `threadId` 
FROM `chat_messages` AS `ChatMessage` WHERE `ChatMessage`.`thread_id` = 2 ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `thread_id` AS `threadId` FROM `chat_messages` AS `ChatMessage` 
WHERE `ChatMessage`.`thread_id` = 3 ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1) AS sub) AS `ChatMessage` LEFT OUTER JOIN `USUARIOS` AS `user` ON `ChatMessage`.`userId` = `user`.`USER_ID`;
```

The code is the same, but as seen, it makes some things differently: **SELECT `ChatMessage`.**
The userId that is well generated in localhost, is now specified as **`ChatMessage`.`userId`
**

Can anyone tell me why this could happen? As I say the endpoint is the same, I migrated the tables again and again and nothing seems to change.

Thank you in advance!